# WP Advanced Custom Fields: WYSIWYG Insert link to media

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

I hope I can explain this properly... and unfortunately I don't have code to show, but I've researched all over and can't find any anything to help. For reference, I'm also using the ACF plugin for WordPress. I have the WYSIWYG set to 'Visual Only' and 'Simple' in ACF.

Essentially, I'm trying to customize the WordPress WYSIWYG menu, in particular the 'Insert/Edit link' button actions. Currently when you click on that button in the WYSIWYG editor, it first shows a mini editor like such:

[image]

And when you click on the gear icon 'Link Options' it brings up more options like so:

[image]

But the only links in the list are Pages (or posts, but this site doesn't have any posts).

**What I'd like to do is also include links to media documents in the list.**
Something like this must be possible, but I can't for the life of me figure out where to edit this. I imagine it must be some part of TinyMCE but I can't be sure. Has anyone dealt with this?

**EDIT: [See my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51803828/3053568) which includes edits to the accepted answer to see the final product.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these to your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
// Query for attachments
add_filter( 'wp_link_query_args', 'my_modify_link_query_args' );
function my_modify_link_query_args( $query ) {
    $query['post_status'] = array('publish','inherit');
    return $query;
}

// Link to media file URL instead of attachment page
add_filter( 'wp_link_query', 'my_modify_link_query_results' );  
function my_modify_link_query_results( $results, $query ) {
    foreach ( $results as &$result ) {
        if ( 'Media' === $result['info'] ) {
            $result['permalink'] = wp_get_attachment_url( $result['ID'] );
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: This was essentially what I needed! While I had to make some personal edits to fit my exact needs I'm going to except your answer, as I wouldn't have been able to do it without you. Thanks!

Comment: Not working with the current version of WordPress at the time of writing, has something changed in the way this gets applied?
I'm getting server errors and the link menu isn't showing any pages, posts, or attachments.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't have been able to solve this without [Outsource WordPress's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51796749/3053568), so I accepted that answer given the question, but I made a few adjustments to fit my specific needs. Here's a list of changes:

- I only wanted post_types of '*page*' and '*attachment*' (no 'post')
- `$result['info']` has been updated from 'Media' to MIME type where appropriate
- '*media*' links are sorted alphabetically first by MIME type then title, with '*pages*' always on top sorted alphabetically by title
- I was going to filter out certain MIME types but decided against it (left in comment)

Here's the final code added to *functions.php*:

```
// Query for attachments
add_filter( 'wp_link_query_args', 'link_query_args' );
function link_query_args( $query ) {
    $query['post_status'] = array('publish','inherit');
    $query['post_type'] = array('page','attachment');
    return $query;
}

// Link to media file URL instead of attachment page
add_filter( 'wp_link_query', 'link_query_results' );  
function link_query_results( $results ) {
    foreach ( $results as $index => &$result ) {
        if ( $result['info'] === 'Page' ) {
            $pageArr[] = $result;
        }
        if ( $result['info'] === 'Media' ) {
            /*
            // Remove certain MIME types
            if( in_array( get_post_mime_type( $result['ID'] ), array('image/jpeg') )  ){
                unset($results[$index]);
            }
            */
            $result['permalink'] = wp_get_attachment_url( $result['ID'] );
            $result['info'] = get_post_mime_type( $result['ID'] );
            $mediaArr[] = $result;
        }
    }
    usort($pageArr, function($a, $b){
        return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
    });
    array_multisort(array_column($mediaArr, 'info'), SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, 
                    array_column($mediaArr, 'title'), SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, 
                    $mediaArr);
    $results = array_merge($pageArr, $mediaArr);
    return $results;
}
```